# elastic 6.3 - Trying to add wildcard feature to match queries

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

Below is my existing query (which works as intended).
I tried several scenarios swapping 'wildcard' for 'match' and/or 'query', etc.
What I would like to do is search for prop* which should also return propeller.
Currently the * is considered whitespace.
I've included the entire query although the area of interest is the "should" segment
Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
{"size": 1000,"sort" : [ {"randomnum" : {"order" : "desc"}},"_score"], "version": true,
   "query" : {
            "bool" : {
              "minimum_should_match": 1,
"must" : [{"match": { "source":    { "query": "<Clearance New Rebuilt","operator": "or"}}},
          {"match": { "today": {"query": "<2021-31>", "operator": "and"}}},
          {"match": { "state": {"query": "<California,Florida>", "operator": "or"}}}],
"should" : [
            {"match": { "description":    { "query": "Michigan bronze left-hand prop", "fuzziness": "0","operator": "and"}}},
            {"match": { "title":    { "query": "Michigan bronze left-hand prop", "fuzziness": "0","operator": "and"}}}
              ]
,"must_not":[
{"match":{"description": "damaged"}}
]
         }
      }
}
```

Comment: can you please share your index mapping ? And are you trying to match `Michigan bronze left-hand prop` for `Michigan bronze left-hand propeller` ?

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions and wildcards are slower, above implementation can also be achieved using [match_phrase_prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html) which has better performance

> Returns documents that contain the words of a provided text, in the
> same order as provided. The last term of the provided text is treated
> as a prefix, matching any words that begin with that term.

"match_phrase_prefix": {
"title": "Michigan bronze left-hand prop"
}

This will search for Michigan bronze left-hand prop*.

If you intend to do prefix search on  multiple tokens or order of tokens can vary , you can use prefix query

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "prefix": {
                        "title": {
                            "value": "michigan"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "prefix": {
                        "title": {
                            "value": "bronze"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "prefix": {
                        "title": {
                            "value": "left"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "prefix": {
                        "title": {
                            "value": "hand"
                        }
                    }
                },
{
                    "prefix": {
                        "title": {
                            "value": "prop"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```